# ngClass not showing 2 classes simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've got a ngClass directive that doesn't show both classes stated, only one of them.
I've called the classes by { className: condition, className2: condition }. These are supposed to show when some non-exclusive conditions are met, but I am not able to see both of them (it's supposed to show two little '!' markers, one for each class)

The ngClass directive

```
<div class="custom-table-row" *ngFor="let item of list;" (click)="select( item, $event )" (dblclick)="view( item )"
[ngClass]="{ 'active': action.exists( item ),  'notificationempaque': tieneEmpaque( item ),   'notificationauto': item.actividadPendiente( auth.user.id )}" >
```

The 2 classes here are notificationempaque and notificationauto:

Here is the css style sheets:

```
.table-custom .custom-table-row.notification:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(../img/icons/notification_icon.svg);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 1px;
  top: 6px;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-animation: wobble-ver-left 0.8s infinite forwards;
  animation: wobble-ver-left 0.8s infinite forwards;
```

Both are the same, but one of them has a different starting position, so they don't overlap.

I've tried writing it in different ways, using 2 ngClases, and creating a style sheet for

```
.table-custom .custom-table-row.notificationauto.notificationempaque
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: We don't need the CSS code, but the JavaScript code would help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what JS code you're reffering to, but the only JS code Im using here is the one to evaluate to true or false to decide wheter to show the class or not.
edit: these are proven to be working. can they be the cause of the problem?

Comment: you can do an alternate like `[class.active]="action.exists(item)" [class.notificationempaque]="tieneEmpaque(item)"`

Comment: It shows the same results, sadly. Thank you though!

Comment: Have you tried digging into  `action.exists( item )`, `tieneEmpaque(item)`, and `item.actividadPendiente( auth.user.id )` to make sure they evaluate as expected?

Comment: Yes, the evaluations are working properly. Even if that was not the case, when I set them both to 'true' they still behave like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to apply two `:before` selectors to one element. That is not possible. There can be only one `:before` and one `:after` selector for each element.

You are just overwriting it now.

For this to work, I would suggest you to wrap one div inside the other and apply the `:before` to different divs.

**OR**

Omit the `:before` and add your images via JavaScript instead of CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was the issue. I was not able to wrap it in another div, due to 'item' being array elements, but I was able to get both classes to show using :after on one of them, even though Im not quite sure why it worked. Thank you!